# Yoast SEO Sitemap Limit

Tags: woocommerce, sitemap

Wordpress Query:

1. I am handling my client woocommerce website with 1.3 million products (digital services)
2. Using Yoast SEO premium plugin. This plugin splits the entire product URL in a bucket of 1000's product sitemap URL per child sitemap
3. Maximum number of child sitemap under sitemap_index file is limited to 1000

In above scenario, only 1000,000 URLs can be present in the sitemap. How to add the remaining 300,000 URLs in the sitemap?

Should I increase the number of URLs per child sitemap from 1000 to 2000 to adjust all 1.3 million URLs?

If yes, will it increase the burden on the server? I am on Hostgator VPS Snappy 4000.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score -1):

If you are worried about Google Search Console limit, it is 50.000 URL-s per sitemap file